# Decompiling apk to add ads?

Tags: android, launcher

I use this..
`http://gotheme.goforandroid.com:8080/goLockerTheme/user/jspController/welcome?locale=en_US` 
tool to make custom go locker themes. Now I want to publish it to the market with a `startapp`
ad included.

I know this is possible because these guys `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Slingshot+Go+Lockers` have been doing it for all their apps.

How do I do it?

EDIT: If there is any other way (other than decompiling) to do it plz let me know....

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it's not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler#Legality . However, taking someone else's commercial app, adding your own special sauce and reselling it usually is, depending on the EULA.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a program like dex2jar or apktool to view the source, but you would never be able to understand it.

Comment: I could use these tools but putting an Ad involves importing a jar lib, adding permissions and code....will I be able to do all this???

Comment: Probably not without alot of knowledge on how to poperly modify obfuscated source code, sorry.